# Printing an InfoPath 2010 form in SharePoint 2010

Tags: infopath, sharepoint-2010

Does anyone know where the option to print an infopath form (in my case a customized list form) exists in SharePoint 2010?

In MOSS this functionality comes out of the box but either I am missing something really simple or my environment isn't set up properly.

Does anyone have any suggestions they can offer?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is also built into SP2010 / Infopath 2010. However there is no way to configure it within Sharepoint - but only in InfoPath.

In Infopath under File > Info > Form Options you have several possibilities to restrict users from doing stuff with your form. To get the **print** functionality you need to enable the InfoPath Ribbon ("Show InfoPath commands in Ribbon or toolbar" and also the *Print Preview* option and you are good to go. See the below image for the correct settings in the dialog:
[image]